# Push de arrays en este juego no me va

Tags: javascript, html

alguien me podria decir como hago para que despues de cada movimiento, tenga un travelLog con las coordenadas por las que he pasado, y guardado en mi travelLog array de mi objeto? Obviamente hago rover.travelLog y me da todo el tiempo la coordenada actual, varios arrays pero con las mismas, entiendo porque pasa esto pero no caigo en como guardar las anteriores.

```js
//UPDATE INFO
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(messages, 1000);
});

function messages() {
  let mensajeDireccion = document.getElementById('direction').textContent = 'rover is facing ' + rover.direction;
  let mensajePosicion = document.getElementById('direction2').textContent = rover.position[0] + ',' + rover.position[1];
}

//ROVER GRID
let grid = [
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 'o', 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'o', 7, 8, 9],
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  [0, 1, 'o', 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 'o', 7, 8, 9],
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
];


//ROVER OBJECT
let rover = {
  direction: 'N',
  position: [0, 0],
  travelLog: []
};


//LOGIC DECISSIONS
document.getElementById("decision").onkeyup = function(e) {

  let texto = e.target.value;

  let textoSanedo = texto.replace(" ", "").toUpperCase();

  e.target.value = textoSanedo;

  let commands;
  for (var i = 0; i < textoSanedo.length; i++) {
    commands = textoSanedo[i];
  }

  switch (commands) {
    case 'L':
      forward(rover);
      break;
    case 'R':
      turnRight(rover);
      break;
    case 'F':
      moveForward(rover);
      break;
    case 'B':
      moveBackwards(rover);
      break;
  }
  // console.log(rover.position);
  // console.log(rover.travelLog);

  // for (var j = 0; j < rover.position.length; j++) {
  //   // rover.travelLog.push(rover.position[i]);
  //   console.log(rover.position[i]);
  // }

  if (rover.position[0] < 0 || rover.position[0] > 9 || rover.position[1] < 0 || rover.position[1] > 9) {
    alert('out');
  }
  return;
};



//TURN LEFT
function turnLeft(rover) {
  switch (rover.direction) {
    case 'N':
      rover.direction = 'W';
      break;
    case 'W':
      rover.direction = 'S';
      break;
    case 'S':
      rover.direction = 'E';
      break;
    case 'E':
      rover.direction = 'N';
      break;
  }
  messages();
}

//TURN RIGHT
function turnRight(rover) {
  switch (rover.direction) {
    case 'N':
      rover.direction = 'E';
      break;
    case 'E':
      rover.direction = 'S';
      break;
    case 'S':
      rover.direction = 'W';
      break;
    case 'W':
      rover.direction = 'N';
      break;
  }
  messages();
}

//MOVE FORWARD
function moveForward(rover) {
  switch (rover.direction) {
    case 'N':
      rover.position[0]--;

      break;
    case 'W':
      rover.position[1]--;

      break;
    case 'S':
      rover.position[0]++;

      break;
    case 'E':
      rover.position[1]++;

      break;
  }
  rover.travelLog.push(rover.position);
  messages();
}

//MOVE BACKWARDS
function moveBackwards(rover) {
  switch (rover.direction) {
    case 'N':
      rover.position[0]++;

      break;
    case 'W':
      rover.position[1]++;


      break;
    case 'S':
      rover.position[0]--;

      break;
    case 'E':
      rover.position[1]--;

      break;
  }
  rover.travelLog.push(rover.position);
  messages();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>rover</title>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="decision" type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="l: Left, r: Right, f: Forward, b: Backwards">
  <p id="direction"></p>
  <p id="direction2"></p>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: quiero que en travelLog se vea [  [0,0] , [1,0] , [2,0]  ]
Pero obviamente se hace el push de la posicion actual del vehiculo y todo se actualiza, sale esto en rover.travelLog => [  [2,0] , [2,0] , [2,0]  ]  y lo que quiero ver es por donde ha caminado el vehiculo

Comment: te recomiendo editar tu pregunta, colocar el codigo mas sencillo de entender, agregar  los valores que ingresas que te debe retornar y que te retorna

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En lugar de realizar:

```
rover.travelLog.push(rover.position);
```

Copia el arreglo antes de pushiarlo al log:

```
rover.travelLog.push(rover.position.slice());
```

Esto porque de lo contrario simplemente estas guardando la misma referencia del arreglo `rover.position` en el *travelLog*

**EDICION:**

`slice()` como señala en la [documentacion de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/slice):

> El método slice() devuelve una copia de una parte del array dentro de
>   un nuevo array empezando por inicio hasta fin (fin no incluido). El
>   array original no se modificará.

`slice()` sin argumentos copia el arreglo desde la posicion 0

Comment: no entiendo porque un slice ahi... igual tengo que hacer esto en CADA movimiento? ya que depende si esta mirando al sur ete oeste etc, lo debo hacer cada vez?

Comment: cada vez que pushees en el travelLog quieres que el dato que se guarde ahi no se modifique de forma externa, para eso debes copiar el arreglo que agregas

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74154/discussion-on-answer-by-klaimmore-push-de-arrays-en-este-juego-no-me-va).