# No funciona el return cuando el vehiculo se sale del grid

Tags: javascript

ya tenia esto de los boundries cuando el vehiculo se sale de mi grid con un if y le puse return para que pare la ejecucion pero no me sale ahora, quiero que cuando sea menor de 0 o mayor de 9 por cada eje pare la ejecucuion con un return pero al tener varias funciones debo hacer 4 returns? Igual no me sale, si me salgo sigue mostrando valores negativos

```js
//UPDATE INFO
$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout(messages, 1000);
  update();
  resetGame();
});

function messages() {

  with(document){
    let mensajeDireccion = getElementById('direction').textContent = 'rover is facing ' + rover.direction;
    let mensajePosicion = getElementById('direction2').textContent = rover.position[0] + ',' + rover.position[1];
    let mensajeVidas = getElementById('lives').textContent = rover.lives + ' lives';

  }
}

//ROVER GRID
let grid = [
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
];


//ROVER OBJECT
let rover = {
  direction: 'N',
  position: [0, 0],
  obstacles: [],
  lives: 3,
  travelLog: []
};


// RANDOM OBSTACLES PLACEMENT
for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
  let row       = randomObstacle();
  let column = randomObstacle();
  let obstacles = grid[row][column] = 'o';
  let obstacle = [row, column];
  rover.obstacles.push(obstacle);
}

function randomObstacle(){
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
}

//ROVER PLACEMENT ON GRID
function update() {
  grid[rover.position[0]].splice(rover.position[1], 1, 'x');

  //check if crash
  for (var i = 0; i < rover.obstacles.length; i++) {
    if (rover.obstacles[i][0] === rover.position[0] && rover.obstacles[i][1] === rover.position[1]) {
      rover.lives--;
      $('.alerta').addClass('visible');
      $('.alerta').text('you hit an obstaclle ' + rover.lives + ' lives left');
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('.alerta').removeClass('visible');
      },1500);
      messages();
    }

  }

  //when lose
  if (rover.lives === 0) {
    if (confirm('game over, want to play again?')) {
      resetGame();
    }
  }
}

//RESET
function resetGame(){
  grid[rover.position[0]].splice(rover.position[1], 1, 'x');
  rover.lives = 3;
  rover.position = [0,0];
  messages();
}


//LOGIC DECISSIONS
document.getElementById("decision").onkeyup = function(e) {

  let texto = e.target.value;

  let textoSanedo = texto.replace(" ", "").toUpperCase();

  e.target.value = textoSanedo;

  let commands;
  for (var i = 0; i < textoSanedo.length; i++) {
    commands = textoSanedo[i];
  }

  switch (commands) {
    case 'L': forward(rover);break;
    case 'R':turnRight(rover);break;
    case 'F':moveForward(rover);break;
    case 'B':moveBackwards(rover);break;
  }

  //TRAVEL LOG (splice method so doesnt update the same value always)
  rover.travelLog.push(rover.position.slice());
  console.log(rover.travelLog);

  if (rover.position[0] < 0 || rover.position[0] > 9 || rover.position[1] < 0 || rover.position[1] > 9) {
    alert('out of boundries');
  }
  return; //NO FUNCIONA
};

//TURN LEFT
function turnLeft(rover) {
  switch (rover.direction) {
    case 'N':rover.direction = 'W';break;
    case 'W':rover.direction = 'S';break;
    case 'S':rover.direction = 'E';break;
    case 'E':rover.direction = 'N';break;
  }
  messages();
  update();
}

//TURN RIGHT
function turnRight(rover) {
  switch (rover.direction) {
    case 'N':rover.direction = 'E';break;
    case 'E':rover.direction = 'S';break;
    case 'S':rover.direction = 'W';break;
    case 'W':rover.direction = 'N';break;
  }
  messages();
  update();
}

//MOVE FORWARD
function moveForward(rover) {
  switch (rover.direction) {
    case 'N':rover.position[0]--;break;
    case 'W':rover.position[1]--;break;
    case 'S':rover.position[0]++;break;
    case 'E':rover.position[1]++;break;
  }
  messages();
  update();
}

//MOVE BACKWARDS
function moveBackwards(rover) {
  switch (rover.direction) {
    case 'N':rover.position[0]++;break;

    case 'W':rover.position[0]++;break;

    case 'S':rover.position[0]--;break;

    case 'E':rover.position[0]--;break;
  }
  messages();
  update();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>rover</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <input id="decision" type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="l: Left, r: Right, f: Forward, b: Backwards" autocomplete="off">
  <p id="direction"></p>
  <p id="direction2"></p>
  <p id="lives"></p>
  <div class="alerta"></div>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"> </script> -->
  <script src="js/app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo controlo así:

if (roverRobot.position[0] == 9 && posx == 1) {
    console.log("you leave the map, you should select another path [" + roverRobot.position[0] + "," + roverRobot.position[1] + "]");
  } else if (roverRobot.position[0] == 0 && posx == -1) {
    console.log("you leave the map, you should select another path [" + roverRobot.position[0] + "," + roverRobot.position[1] + "]");
  } else {
    roverRobot.tempPosition[0] += posx;
  }

if (roverRobot.position[1] == 9 && posy == 1) {
    console.log("you leave the map, you should select another path [" + roverRobot.position[0] + "," + roverRobot.position[1] + "]");
  } else if (roverRobot.position[1] == 0 && posy == -1) {
    console.log("you leave the map, you should select another path [" + roverRobot.position[0] + "," + roverRobot.position[1] + "]");
  } else {
    roverRobot.tempPosition[1] += posy;
  }

Te dejo un enlance a codepen para que veas el codigo, ten encuenta que este codigo se ejecuta en la consola del navegador (F12 para abrirla).

https://codepen.io/SahJ/pen/oqXGOB